# PHP including HTML in readfile

Tags: php

I have the following code which kind of works but for some reason the $download includes the part inside  into the downloaded file.

```
<form method="post">
<button id="click" name="click">Download</button>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['click'])){
$files = scandir('/local/path', SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$newest_file = $files[0];
$download = $newest_file;

header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$download.'"');
readfile("/local/path/$download");
}
?>
```

Downloaded file

```
form method="post">
<button id="click" name="click">Download</button>
</form>

Start-of-the-actual-log
blabla
blabla
blabla
```

What is causing this to happen? I only want to download the newest file in a folder.

Comment: In your code, you specifically output that HTML at the top of the script.

Comment: @NigelRen I'm sorry, I'm pretty much a noob. My understanding of the code is that it scans the local path and then grabs the file. I'm not sure how it is including the HTML part.

Answer (score 1):

Dont print anything or send header before downloading, look at this :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['click'])){
    $files = scandir('/local/path', SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
    $newest_file = $files[0];
    $download = $newest_file;

    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$download.'"');
    readfile("/local/path/$download");
}else{
     echo'
     <form method="post">
         <button id="click" name="click">Download</button>
     </form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Putting the code (without the else statement) serves just the file. But I still don't understand why the HTML gets included in the download to being with.